# What would be the fastest way to find an item by a multivalued key in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I will need to parse thousands upon thousands of simple entries in C++. I've only ever programmed in C, so I might be missing some higher functions to make this task easier.

An entry consists of 4 separate values: a `sender`, a `receiver`, a `date`, and a `type of mail`. Three of these are `string` values, the last one is an `integer`. My goal (after all entries are processed) is to print out all different entries that were received on the input and how many times each of these entries were received.

That means that if there was the same sender, receiver, date, and type of mail, multiple times on the input, the output would say that this entry was received e.g 5 times.

What would be the best way to do this? I tried C++ `map` but was unable to make it work.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` and combine 4 values into a single string might be good enough.

Comment: It appears clear that you know that `map` (and `unordered_map`) is the solution here, so it's unclear what your question actually is. You should post the code you tried, and we can help you fix that.

Comment: Unrelated, consider storing dates using `std::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>`

Comment: *What would be the best way to do this?* -- The "best" way should be a "good way", or a "better way", or a "fast way".  The "best" way is opinion-based.

Comment: No need to use C++. If you have a Unix system, do `sort <file> | uniq -c` and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest defining a class with an `operator<` that makes it possible to store  instances of the class in a `std::map`. The `std::map` can be used to map *from* objects comparing equal *to* a count. Objects are considered equal if neither `lhs < rhs` nor `rhs < lhs` is true so only the `operator<` overload is necessary.

You could also add `operator>>` and `operator<<` overloads to make it possible to read and write objects from streams.

It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

struct foo {
    std::string sender;
    std::string receiver;
    std::string date;
    int type_of_mail;

    // compare two foo instances:
    bool operator<(const foo& rhs) const {
        return std::tie(sender, receiver, date, type_of_mail) <
               std::tie(rhs.sender, rhs.receiver, rhs.date, rhs.type_of_mail);
    }

    // read a foo from an istream:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, foo& f) {
        return is >> f.sender >> f.receiver >> f.date >> f.type_of_mail;
    }

    // write a foo to an ostream:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo& f) {
        return os << f.sender << ' ' << f.receiver << ' ' << f.date << ' '
                  << f.type_of_mail;
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::map<foo, unsigned> counts;
    foo tmp;

    // read foos from any istream
    while(std::cin >> tmp) {
        ++counts[tmp];        // count
    }

    // print the count for each
    for(const auto&[f, count] : counts) {
        std::cout << count << ' ' << f << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8hP48a6zc)

Answer (score 0):

You might store it in a set / multiset, using a struct that implements comparison:

```
struct Entry {
    friend bool operator<(const Entry& lhs, const Entry& rhs) {
        if (lhs.sender < rhs.sender) return true;
        if (lhs.sender > rhs.sender) return false;
        if (lhs.receiver < rhs.receiver) return true;
        if (lhs.receiver > rhs.receiver) return false;
        if (lhs.date < rhs.date) return true;
        if (lhs.date > rhs.date) return false;
        if (lhs.type_of_mail < rhs.type_of_mail) return true;
        return false;
    }

    std::string sender;
    std::string receiver;
    std::string date; // this should be a proper date time, otherwise DST & timezones might be a problem
    int type_of_mail; // this should be enum
};

int main() {
   std::set<Entry> entries;
   // or
   std::multiset<Entry> entries_duplications_allowed;
   // you might insert elements here
   // you might loop over entries using e.g. range for here
}
```

Comment: Usage of `std::tie` would greatly simplify your `operator <`

Comment: You meant `std::multiset`? Since `std::set` doesn't allow duplicates and OP wants to count the occurrence.

Comment: @LouisGo It was not clear to me whether duplications are possible. If it is, then we certainly need `std::multiset` (updated the answer).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand that it's also a possibility and why you say so. In prod code, I'd use boost or a custom library to provide `<` for me. This is to show the internal workings of it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a single data table along with an index table for each field you want to search.  (Actually this smells like you should be using a database, rather than writing one)

Place all your records into a `std::vector<Record>`.
Create a `std::map<key_text, vector_index>` for each key field.

To find a record:

1. Search the appropriate `map` (index table) with the key (string).
2. If found, extract the index field.
3. Use the index filed for the `std::vector<Record>`.

Multiple field key search is more difficult and may take up more room (if you are using an indexing data structure).

IMHO, your best route is to use a database.